# How to map 'gh' to save when not in insert mode?

Tags: vim, key

I wanted to press 'gh' quickly instead of :w to save what I'm working on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Writes file when <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> pressed in normal mode**

```
:nnoremap gh :w<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "Not in insert mode" you mean in normal mode, you can put this in your `.vimrc`.

`nnoremap gh :w<CR>`